# Generalization of product theorem in group theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, maximal-subgroup

I was taught the following group theory theorem:

> Let H and K be subgroups of a group G and assume HK = KH
>   $H \vee K=HK=KH$

which sometimes is called the product theorem (Ledermann, Introduction to group theory).

Afterwards, I studied the following theorem:

> Let H and K be subgroups of a group G then 
>   $H \vee K=\{h_1k_1h_2k_2...h_rk_r | h_i \in H,k_i \in K, r \ge 1\}$

which seems to be a generalization of the first one. To my intuition it says that removing commutative properties is substituted by infinite repetition.

¿Do you know if this result has a name?¿Do you know any applications of it?

Comment: WHat is the theorem? The only thing more or less close to what you apparently mean is that if $\;H,K\;$ are subgroups of $\;G\;$ , then $\;HK\;$ is *also* a subgroup if and only if $\;HK=KH\;$ .

Comment: I'm not sure if $H\vee K$ is common notation for "the subgroup generated by $H$ and $K$." Certainly $\vee$ is common notation for the join operation in an abstract lattice, and the collection of subgroups of a fixed group form a concrete lattice, but still. I am used to $\langle X\rangle$ denoting the subgroup generated by a set $X$, in which case we can use either $\langle H\cup K\rangle$ or $\langle H,K\rangle$ to refer to the subgroup generated by $H$ and $K$.

Comment: Anyway, the result seems too elementary to have a name. I know for a fact I've implicitly used this kind of thinking a lot when dealing with groups, but I didn't plan ahead to form any kind of documentary memory of all the instances I used it.